# Custom 404 with HttpListener

Tags: c#, .net, http, .net-4.5, httplistener

I'm having an issue with HttpListener, it's working just fine (including returning 404) but if i write anything to the output Stream (to return custom html for 404) then even if i set status code = 404 firebug displays status 200 ok, as soon as i remove the custom html it does see a 404 as expected.

As is i get a 404, if i uncomment the 2 commented lines i get the HTML i want displayed but a 200 while i expect a 404 :

```
    //var buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("<html><head></head><body><h1>404 not found</h1></body></html>");
    //ctx.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    ctx.Response.StatusCode = 404;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the HTTP protocol requires that the status code be sent before the content, once you write to the output stream, Status 200 is automatically sent for you followed by whatever you write into the stream. If you try to set the status code after writing to the output stream, it is already too late.

Comment: you think MS could have designed the interface in a way to make this obvious.